# Jmeter: ctx.getCurrentSampler() and ctx.getPreviousSampler() return same requests

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

[Test Plan or reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MclYL.png)This is my first time working with Jmeter.
I have 2 questions over here

1.While trying to execute methods ctx.getCurrentSampler() and ctx.getPreviousSampler() in Beanshell PreProcessor, its returning me same request for both the methods.

2. Arguments arguments = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments();

log.info("count of argument= " +arguments.getArgumentCount()); ==> returns me 0

Though log.info("Current Sampler "+ctx.getCurrentSampler()); returns me the request, not sure why the count returns 0.

FYI: I am passing requests using a csv file

Can someone help me to figure out if I am missing anything over here

Comment: Can you show your test plan?

Comment: @user7294900 I have updated description with the screenshot of test plan. I tried to move beanshell processor at Test Plan level, thread group level and HTTP Request level as well. Still it returns same results